# PHP+jQuery game security

Tags: php, jquery, security

I am making a game with PHP and jQuery, but I have some problems with security. It's a typing game, and when player types combination correctly, jQuery sends ajax request to PHP and PHP adds 10 points to session. Here is my code:

```
$('body').on('keyup','.codes_input',function() {
    if($('.codes_input').val() == $('.code').html()) {
        $.post(url+'/save_results',{_token:token});
        points=points+10;
        $('.code').html(randomString());
        $('.codes_input').val('');
        $('.points').html(points);
    }
});
```

However, my friends could simply do many such `$.post(url+'/save_results',{_token:token});`requests in chrome extention (if I understood correctly) and got 1000 or even more points (cheating). Is there a way to avoid this? I can't find other way of programming this... Thanks for your help, sorry for my poor english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can always be seen by the user, so you cannot really build a secure application like this.
The way to go would be to check via Javascript whether the code is correct (as you already do), and then send the code to the PHP script and validate it there as well.

Comment: you mean sending code and input to php file and check there?

Comment: Yes, and then you return something like a boolean back to Javascript to give graphical feedback to the user. jQuery's $.post can handle that as well, you could for example encode it via JSON.

Comment: but if attacker can use that $.post in my way, he also can send correct code (`var code=$('.code').html();`) and php will return true, so result will be same as mine, or I don't understand something? :?

Comment: You would have to remove the `.code` element as well. Even without any post requests the user could simply look at your site via e.g. FireBug, find the value and enter it into your input field.

Comment: and what if i stop game on `blur` then?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you mean by that. What I mean to say is that all the code validation only happens in a PHP script, where the user can't see it. The only thing Javascript then does is send the code you wrote to the PHP script, which then returns either true or false, depending on whether the code was correct. Javascript and the HTML document must not contain any information about which codes are valid.

Comment: yea, I understand this, just thinking will it be secure. thanks :) see what i will do

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Move the logic of evaluating and awarding points to you PHP layer.

Use the jQuery with HTML Websockets just to submit the answer  .

As an example architecture, you can have a look at the following:

1. [Javascript and PHP for real-time multiplayer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/33341) <- Join this SE network
2. [Real Time Multiplayer in HTML5](http://buildnewgames.com/real-time-multiplayer/)